# Could not seem to make Quartz .Net work on VB.Net Web Application Project

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, quartz.net

I followed the Quartz manual to the dot and still I'm not sure why it isn't picking up the GetDeal.vb (Quartz job) in **Global.asax**. It never went into the **_scheduler.JobGroupNames**
 and **_scheduler.TriggerGroupNames** loop as follows:

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim factory As ISchedulerFactory = New StdSchedulerFactory()
    _scheduler = factory.GetScheduler()
    _scheduler.Start()

    If _scheduler.IsStarted Then
        Dim jobs As String = ""
        Dim jobGroup As String = ""
        For Each jobGroup In _scheduler.JobGroupNames
            Dim jobName As String
            For Each jobName In _scheduler.GetJobNames(jobGroup)
                jobs = jobs + " " + jobName
            Next
        Next

        jobs = ""
        For Each jobGroup In _scheduler.TriggerGroupNames
            Dim jobName As String
            For Each jobName In _scheduler.GetTriggerNames(jobGroup)
                jobs = jobs + " " + jobName
            Next
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

I've attached a link to download my Project here. Any advices on how to make it work?
- http://www.uniquevolve.com/YouMeCoupon.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the namespace of your job this way: `Namespace Jobs`

This is the complete file:

```
Imports Quartz

' Namespace YouMeCoupon.Jobs
Namespace Jobs

Public Class GetDeal : Implements Quartz.IJob


    Public Sub Execute(ByVal context As Quartz.JobExecutionContext) Implements Quartz.IJob.Execute
        Dim data As JobDataMap = context.MergedJobDataMap
        'Dim url As String = data.GetString("URL")

        Try
            Dim a As String
            a = "testing"

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
End Class

End Namespace
```

I would suggest you to use the logging system to debug Quartz.net.
You have to have these references:

Common.Logging.dll
Common.Logging.NLog.dll
NLog.dll

Then you can add a config file for NLog (NLog.config)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
    <targets>
        <target name="DebugHandler" type="File" filename="${basedir}/_Logs/${date:format=yyyyMMdd}_${level}.Log"
            layout="${longdate} ${logger}   ${aspnet-session:variable=UserName} ${threadid} ${environment}  ${identity} ${aspnet-request}   ${message}  ${exception}" />
        <target name="ErrorHandler" type="File" filename="${basedir}/_Logs/${date:format=yyyyMMdd}_${level}.Log"
            layout="${longdate} ${logger}   ${aspnet-session:variable=UserName} ${threadid} ${environment}  ${aspnet-request}   ${message}  ${exception}" />
        <target name="FatalHandler" type="File" filename="${basedir}/_Logs/${date:format=yyyyMMdd}_${level}.Log"
            layout="${longdate} ${logger}   ${aspnet-session:variable=UserName} ${threadid} ${environment}  ${aspnet-request}   ${message}  ${exception}" />
        <target name="GenericHandler" type="File" filename="${basedir}/_Logs/${date:format=yyyyMMdd}_${level}.Log"
            layout="${longdate} ${logger}   ${aspnet-session:variable=UserName} ${threadid} ${environment}  ${aspnet-request}   ${message}  ${exception}" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" level="Debug" appendTo="DebugHandler" />
        <logger name="*" level="Error" appendTo="ErrorHandler" />
        <logger name="*" level="Fatal" appendTo="FatalHandler" />
        <logger name="*" levels="Info,Warn" appendTo="GenericHandler" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

and change your web.config adding these sections:

```
<sectionGroup name="common">
  <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging"/>
</sectionGroup>
```

and

```
  <common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.NLog.NLogLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging.NLog">
        <arg key="configType" value="FILE" />
        <arg key="configFile" value="~/NLog.config" />
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>
```

Now, everything should be traced in your _Logs (which you have to add to your project). It's easier for you to understand what's happening.
You can find your updated solutions with the logging [here](http://cid-669adf1af64df389.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/YouMeCoupon.zip). 
Check also Quartz.net version. It seems to me that you're not using the last one: 1.3.

Comment: Changing the Namespace from YouMeCoupon.Jobs to Jobs did the job. You, Sir LeftyX, are amazing! Thanks for showing me how logging is done. I had no idea how to write to log before this. :)

Comment: Logging is very important. That's how I've found your problem ;-)